# How to get data from struts2 action with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-maps, struts2

I have an Struts2 Web with GoogleMaps. I want to load a list of markers which are saved in a SQL DDBB. To do this, I tried with jQuery and Ajax. Here you are the code:

loadMarkers.java

```
  public class loadMarkers extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware,ServletResponseAware{

//Variables de sesion/cookie
FunctionClass ses;
protected HttpServletResponse servletResponse;
protected HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
private String userID="";

//Variables del marker
private List<marker> markersList = new ArrayList<marker>();

public String execute() throws Exception{
    FunctionClass friends = new FunctionClass();

    //Leemos de la cookie
    for(Cookie c : servletRequest.getCookies()) {
        if (c.getName().equals("userID"))
            userID = (c.getValue());
    } 
    System.out.println("en el loadMarkers");
    connectionBBDD con = new connectionBBDD();
    markersList = con.loadMarkers(userID);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to use the markerList array in Javascript, to create the markers.

This is the struts.xml file:

```
<package name="jsonActions" namespace="/test" extends="json-default">
    <action name="LoadMarkers" class="web.localizadroid.maps.loadMarkers">
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
        <result type="json">
        <param name="root">markersList</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

And here you are the Javascript (jQuery) code:

```
function loadMarkersJ(){
alert("dentro");
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : "LoadMarkers",
    dataType: "json",       
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data);
        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage ('http://i53.tinypic.com/ettquh.png');
        var jSon_Object = eval("(" + data + ")");
        //For para analizar los datos (Json) obtenidos de la BBDD
        for (x = 0; x < jSon_Object.length; x++) {

            var markersArray = [];

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(jSon_Object[x].lat, jSon_Object[x].lon);

            markerLoaded = new google.maps.Marker( {
                position : myLatlng,
                map : map,
                icon: image,
                title: "NOMBRE: " + jSon_Object[x].tarjetName + "\n" + "ANOTACIONES: " + jSon_Object[x].anotaciones + "\n" + "TIME: " + jSon_Object[x].time
            });
            markersArray.push(markerLoaded);

            if (markersArray) {
                for (i in markersArray) {
                    alert("entro en forColocaMarkers");     
                    if (markersArray[i].getAnimation() != null) {
                        markersArray[i].setAnimation(null);
                    } else {
                            markersArray[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                    }

                    markersArray[i].setMap(map);        
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

}

From `success : function(data) {` to the end, is JavaScript code to create de markers, and this it's OK. The problem is whith ajax, because I don't get to obtain markerList Array by jSon data return...I think that the problem is in the url attribute from $.ajax...I tried loadMarkers.action and loadMarkers, but nothing happens. When I execute the web, only prints the alert `alert("dentro")`, the alert `alert(data)` never has been printed.

I have forgotten to add the code where I call the Javascript function (loadMarkersJ). Here you are:

```
<p><s:a  action="LoadMarkers.action" namespace="/test" onclick="loadMarkersJ(this)">Cargar Marcadores S</s:a></p>
```

Somebody can help me please?

Comment: Try using Firebug to see the details of the Ajax request and response.

Comment: Agree with the above, according to your code you should be able to point your browser at "/test/LoadMarkers" and get a page/file of json if you don't then no amount of JS is going to help. I say page/file because FF will generally produce a file to save and Chome will display a page of json.

Comment: OH!!!Now I have this problem! In Google CHrome I can dispaly de Json file, and in IE I can download it, but I don't want this! I want to use de data what contains json to create the markers!How I have to do?I don't understend what do  you want to say with "you should be able to point your browser at /test/LoadMarkers...."

Answer (score 2):

Have you consider using the [Struts2-jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)  It REALLY simplifies ajax development with Struts2, used it by myself

Comment: Yes I have consider to use Struts2-jQuery plugin but I don't know how to do all the code that I showed with Struts2-jQuery plugin tags...

Comment: With the Struts2-jQuery-plugin you can use a library tags, like <sj:form> for example...do you see it?

Comment: This is showcase for struts2-jQuery plugin http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action. You can download all sources from that resource. I can tell from my experience: In 4 days I learned how to use plugin and rewrited my app with 6 actions to work without page refreshes :) So, it worth to study it

Comment: Thank you so match! that web is fantastic! But can you help me with "Remote Link with JSON Result"?? I don't get to load de jSon Result!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't we just provide content-type information in JSP. It works for me.

We don't need to download any plugin to implement JSON support for struts actions.

We can just download any json convertor like [GSON.](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) 
Use following to convert your object into json format.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
json  = gson.toJson(events);
return SUCCESS;
```

In your success JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@page contentType="application/json" %>
<s:property value="json" escape="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false` after the javascript function call.

```
<p><s:a  action="LoadMarkers.action" namespace="/test" onclick="loadMarkersJ(this); return false;">Cargar Marcadores S</s:a></p>
```

Check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20217387/1360694