# How to use struts2 submit tag as button without submitting the form?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts2 framework in my application, I have one button on my JSP page. That is

```
<s:submit type="button" name="btnSave" />
```

Now, I want this button to behave as normal HTML button type should not submit the form and execute the Scripting
function on `onclick` event. That function submit the form using Ajax.

But what happens is Struts2 convert it to

```
<input type="submit" id="add_btnSave" name="btnSave" value="Save"/>
```

And my form is submitted.

1) If I use the HTML button tag it will mess the GUI. As theme of my form is Ajax.

This is a `head` tag with script

```
<head>
<s:head theme="ajax"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("btnSave").click(function(){
alert("aaa");
$.ajax({
url:
type:"POST",
dataType: "json",
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
alert('Error ' + textStatus);
alert(errorThrown);
alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
},
success: function(){
alert('SUCCESS');
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
```

My `body` tag is as followers :

```
<body>
<table border="1" width="80%" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<s:tabbedPanel id="EmpDetail" useSelectedTabCookie="true">
<s:div id="one" label="Emp Reg." theme="ajax" tabindex="0" labelposition="top">
<center>
<s:form name="frmEmpReg" namespace="/" method="post">
EMPLOYEE REGISTRATIOM TAB<br>
<s:actionmessage />
<input type="hidden" name="empbean.id" value="<s:property value="empbean.id"/>"/>
<s:textfield label="Employee First Name" name="empbean.firstName"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield label="Employee Middle Name" name="empbean.middleName"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield label="Employee Last Name" name="empbean.lastName"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield label="Address" name="empbean.address"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield label="State" name="empbean.state"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield label="Employee Designation" name="empbean.designation"></s:textfield>
<s:submit name="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" align="center"/>
</s:form>
</center>
</s:div>
<s:div>
..
..
Other Tabs
</s:div>
</s:tabbedPanel>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

any one have any idea of handling it with Struts2 then please help.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `s:submit` tag the rendered `HTML` output is either `input` or `button` tag but the type is `submit` except for the `image` type.  You can use the code to execute javascript onclick event that doesn't submit the form.

```
<s:submit type="button" onclick="return false;"/>
```

Comment: On click i want to run JS code like in above code: **$("btnSave").click(function(){ **! So if i put onclick=" return false;" my JS code will not be executed. Am i wrong somewhere???

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `preventDefault()`?

```
$("btnSave").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();   
    //..rest of the code
});
```