# send form to server using ajax not working properly struts2

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am new to struts 2 and i want to send form data through ajax and i am able to send the data and the server responds correctly but when the responce comes page goes to another page automatically and shows that responce.

```
var copyEntryFormsubmit = {
            dataType :'json',
            success : function(json) {
                var v = json.parse(json);

            }
        };

        $("#copyEntryForm").submit( function() {
            $(this).ajax(copyEntryFormsubmit);

        });
    <s:form action="copyEventSubmit.action" id="copyEntryForm">
<s:submit key="submit" id="submitcss"></s:submit>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Struts2, but it looks like you need a `preventDefault()` in your jQuery.  The listener on the submit should look like the following:

```
$("#copyEntryForm").submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //code here
});
```

The `e` is the event being passed.  The `preventDefault()` prevents the default behavior, which in this case is the form submitting to the `action` page.  More information on `preventDefault()` can be found in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Comment: when i use this e.preventDefault() it say thay  $(this).ajax(copyEntryFormsubmit); is not a function

Comment: @MOBEENWarar That doesn't have anything to do with `e.preventDefault()` though, it means something else is wrong-like that you're trying to call `ajax` on an object, when it's a top-level jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

Change struts tag as shown below

```
<s:submit type="button" id="submitcss" />
```

and in Javascript as Mathew mentioned use e.preventDefault()

```
$("#submitcss").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();   
     $(this).ajax(copyEntryFormsubmit);
});
```

For more information below go through below link.

[How to use struts2 submit tag as button without submitting the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209645/how-to-use-struts2-submit-tag-as-button-without-submitting-the-form)

**Update:**

you can change your click function like this and give a try

```
$("#submitcss").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    $.ajax({
    dataType :'json',
            success : function(json) {
                var v = json.parse(json);    
            }
   });    
});
```

Comment: when i use this e.preventDefault() it say thay $(this).ajax(copyEntryFormsubmit); is not a function